# Is a supplier liable for missing delivery?

Tags: liability, commerce, tort

I ordered a product online and have been promised the following from the supplier:

> "...your order will be shipped out in approximately two weeks..."

It is now past due. As a result of the delay, I have been suspended from selling on Amazon. There late shipment is my late shipment.

I ordered before I updated my inventory. I received a large list of orders in the following days; however, I did not actually have the products and have not received them one schedule with what my supplier has stated. Because my selling privileges are now suspended I am loosing potential sales. Am I entitled to a won claim from the supplier or is it my fault?

Answer (score 2):

If a contract requires delivery within a certain time frame then the other party can sue for damages if that time frame is breached.

However, "approximately two weeks" is a rather vague time and lacks a certain ... precision. If this was taken to court then 3-4 weeks is easily "approximately two weeks".

Second, damages must be reasonably foreseeable. It is unlikely that the vendor could reasonably foresee that their customer would take "approximately two weeks" and from that state that they have the goods in stock. You clearly didn't.

It's your fault.

Comment: But what about when it goes past the 30-day limit mentioned in [FTC's Mail, Internet, or Telephone Order Merchandise Rule](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/business-guide-ftcs-mail-internet-or-telephone-order).

Comment: Well, you didn't tell the supplier that you would be in trouble if they didn't ship on time, did you? If you had said "I need these items within 14 days, and if I don't get them I will suffer $1 million damages and sue you for the damage", the supplier would likely have said "go and buy somewhere else then".